# Significato della locuzione "in bianco" in questo contesto

Tags: meaning, idioms

Nel romanzo *Il contesto*, di Leonardo Sciascia, ho letto:

> Quando poi seppe che era scomparsa, i sospetti alimentarono la teoria: la donna aveva ordito quel crimine **in bianco**, lasciandone cioè l'esecuzione alla polizia e ai giudici, per liberarsi dal marito quel tanto che le ci voleva per scomparire; e poiché mai una donna, secondo Contrera, scompare da sola, ci doveva pur essere qualcuno che la signora era riuscita a tenere, prima e dopo, nell'ombra più segreta, più impenetrabile.

Nel [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/bianco2/) ho trovato che la locuzione "in bianco" può significare

> senza riuscita, con esito negativo o nullo

Tuttavia, non mi sembra che questa definizione abbia senso in questo contesto. Per questa ragione vi chiedo: potreste spiegarmi cosa vuol dire "in bianco" nel brano sopra citato?

Comment: credo che in questo caso significhi che il crimine era ordito in modo da lasciarla "immacolata" da ogni sospetto.

Comment: Mi ricorda molto l'espressione [sciopero bianco](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sciopero_bianco), se riesco a trovare dei riferimenti decenti scriverò una risposta.

Comment: Credo sia un uso figurato e Sciascia intenda “senza spargimento di sangue”.

Comment: +1 per lo “sciopero bianco” (c'è anche nella Treccani), e ci vedo un nesso indiretto anche con «_matrimonio b._, non consumato; _morte b._, ... (nel linguaggio sindacale, morte per infortunio sul lavoro, detta anche, in tono più polemico, _omicidio b._, spec. quando sia dovuta a incuria o a mancata osservanza delle norme di sicurezza da parte degli imprenditori)».

Answer (score 3):

La spiegazione viene data subito dopo:

> lasciandone cioè l'esecuzione alla polizia e ai giudici

Come un assegno in bianco: chi lo emette non decide a priori chi lo riscuoterà.

Nel caso specifico si fa riferimento al fatto che il crimine non viene eseguito materialmente da chi l'ha concepito.

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE e grazie della risposta!